# Mips function arguments and return values

Tags: mips

I'm trying to make a hash table using mips assembly. My `InsertKey` function is for some reason not working correctly.The console just freezes with no error message when I try to use it.

```
InsertK:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, enterIntPrompt
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $a0, $v0  # key in a0
    li   $t0, 0
    la   $a1, Hash # table address in a1
    bgt  $a0, $t0, JInsertKey
    li   $v0, 4
    la   $a0, notInsertKeyMes
    syscall
    j whileloop
    JInsertKey:
        jal InsertKey
        j   whileloop
```

I suspect that I mess up with my passing values somewhere but I can't find anything. The textbook says it's good practice to use `$v0`-`$v2` registers for return values of function calls and `$a0`-`$a3` for function arguments.
This is the code calling to the `InsertKey` function:

```
InsertKey:
    jal FindKey
    move $t0, $v0 # position in t0
    li   $t1, -1
    bne  $t0, $t1, prints
    bgt  $s1, $s0, dostuff
    li   $v0, 4
    la   $a0, hashTableFullMes
    syscall
    jr $ra
    dostuff:
    jal   HashFunction
    move  $t0, $v0
    li    $t3, 4
    multu $t0, $t3
    mflo  $t3
    la    $a1, Hash
    add   $a1, $a1, $t3 # a1 adress hash[position]
    sw    $a0, ($a1)
    addi  $s0,1
    jr    $ra
    prints:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, keyAlreadyInTableMes
        syscall
        jr $ra
```

`FindKey` and  `HashFunction` are working properly. Can someone identify the problem with this code? I am really out of ideas..

*Edit*: `Findkey` returns the position of the key found else `-1`.

Comment: Stepping through your code in the debugger will help you understand why it does not work: https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/MarsHelpDebugging.html

Comment: I actually did, am using QTSpim and it just crushes when I try to insert a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InsertKey:
    jal FindKey
```

The above causes `$ra` for `InsertKey` to be overwritten with the address of `InsertKey` + 8, so when `InsertKey` returns, it returns to itself, instead of its caller.

You need to save return address and arguments for `InsertKey` before it calls any other functions.